# String SHA-512 Encoding: C# and JAVA result is different

Tags: c#, java, encoding, sha

Im trying to compare two different string encoded by sha512. But, result is different. It can be an encode problem i mean. I hope you can help me.

This is my Java code:

```
    MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512"); 
    digest.update(MyString.getBytes()); 
    byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

    // Create Hex String
    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
        String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
        while (h.length() < 2)
            h = "0" + h;
        hexString.append(h);
    }
    return hexString.toString();
```

and, this is my C# code:

```
        UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
        byte[] hashValue;
        byte[] message = UE.GetBytes(MyString);

        SHA512Managed hashString = new SHA512Managed();
        string hex = "";

        hashValue = hashString.ComputeHash(message);
        foreach (byte x in hashValue)
        {
            hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", x);

        }
        return hex;
```

Where is the problem ? Thx much guys

**UPDATE**

If i don't specify encoding type, it supposes Unicode i think. Result is this (without specifying anything):

```
Java SHA: a99951079450e0bf3cf790872336b3269da580b62143af9cfa27aef42c44ea09faa83e1fbddfd1135e364ae62eb373c53ee4e89c69b54a7d4d268cc2274493a8

C# SHA: 70e6eb559cbb062b0c865c345b5f6dbd7ae9c2d39169571b6908d7df04642544c0c4e6e896e6c750f9f135ad05280ed92b9ba349de12526a28e7642721a446aa
```

Instead, if i specify UTF-16 in Java:

```
Java UTF-16: SHA f7a587d55916763551e9fcaafd24d0995066371c41499fcb04614325cd9d829d1246c89af44b98034b88436c8acbd82cd13ebb366d4ab81b4942b720f02b0d9b
```

It's always different !!!

Comment: What happens when you specify the encoding in `MyString.getBytes()`? (Bad variable name, btw.)

Comment: Have you compared the bytes of `MyString` before computing hash?

Comment: It would be nice to provide us full code samples and your input/output as well.

Comment: Your encoding types are different.

Comment: I hope this isn't used for password hashing...

Comment: I want to unify user and pass string and hashing them toghether. I know that my encoding type are different, but i dont know what encoding type is the right!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`UnicodeEncoding` in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding.aspx) you use corresponds to the **little-endian** UTF-16 encoding, while "UTF-16" in Java corresponds to the **big-endian** UTF-16 encoding. Another difference is that C# doesn't output the Byte Order Marker (called "preamble" in the API) if you don't ask for it, while "UTF-16" in Java generates it always. To make the two programs compatible you can make Java also use the little-endian UTF-16:

```
digest.update(MyString.getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
```

Or you could switch to some other well known encoding, like UTF-8.

Answer (score 6):

Here,

```
digest.update(MyString.getBytes());
```

you should be explicitly specifying the desired character encoding in `String#getBytes()` method. It will otherwise default to the platform default charset as is been obtained by [`Charset#defaultCharset()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset%28%29).

Fix it accordingly:

```
digest.update(MyString.getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
```

It should at least be the same charset as `UnicodeEncoding` is internally using.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, Java has also an enhanced `for` loop and a `String#format()`.

Comment: `UnicodeEncoding` is apparently using UTF-16LE. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is probably that you did not specify the encoding to use when converting the string to bytes, java uses the platform default encoding, while `UnicodeEncoding` seems to use utf-16.

**Edit:**

The [documentation for UnicodeEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/8hs5kkbk.aspx) says

> This constructor creates an instance that uses the **little endian byte order**, provides a Unicode **byte order mark**, and does not throw an exception when an invalid encoding is detected.

Javas "utf-16" however seems to default to **big endian** byte order. With character encodings its better to be really specific, there is an [UnicodeEncoding constructor taking two boolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/984ebfcy.aspx) specifiyng byte order, while in java there is also "utf-16le" and "utf-16be". You could try the following in c#

```
new UnicodeEncoding(true, false) // big endian, no byte order mark
```

and in java

```
myyString.getBytes("utf-16be")
```

Or even better use **"utf-8"** / [Encoding.UTF8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx) in both cases since it is **not affected by different byteorders**.

Comment: Nope. Different result occurs however