# Different UTF-16 Encoding in Java versus C#

Tags: java, c#, unicode

I am struggling with different results when converting a string to bytes in C# vs. Java.

**C#:**

```
byte[] byteArray =  Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes ("chess ¾");
for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write (" " + byteArray[i]);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(byteArray));
```

*displays:*

```
99 0 104 0 101 0 115 0 115 0 32 0 190 0
chess ¾
```

**Java:**

```
byte[] byteArray = "chess ¾".getBytes("UTF-16LE");
for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++)
        System.out.print(" " + (byteArray[i]<0?(-byteArray[i]+128):byteArray[i]));
System.out.println("");
System.out.println(new String(byteAppName,"UTF-16LE"));
```

*displays:*

```
99 0 104 0 101 0 115 0 115 0 32 0 194 0
chess ¾
```

Notice that the second to last value in the byte array is different!  My objective is to encrypt this data and be able to read it from either C# or Java. This difference appears to be an obstacle.

As a side note, before I learned to use Unicode(C#)/UTF-16LE(Java), I was using UTF-8 ...

**C#:** `byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes ("chess ¾");`

*displays:* `99 104 101 115 115 32 194 190`

**Java:** `byteArray = appName.getBytes("UTF-8");`

*displays:* `99 104 101 115 115 32 190 194`

Which, strangely results in the second to last and last bytes being flipped.

Lastly, Unicode for `¾` is decimal 190 (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/BE/index.htm), not decimal 194 (Â) (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00c2/index.htm).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Curious - What kind of output do you get if you manually put the byte array from one into the other (ie: try to decode the bytes)?

Comment: Oh, and welcome to StackOverflow! This is an excellent first question :)

Comment: Good question:  In Java: `byteArray = new byte[] {99, 0, 104, 0, 101, 0, 115, 0, 115, 0, 32, 0, -62, 0};`  displays: `99 0 104 0 101 0 115 0 115 0 32 0 190 0` `chess Â`

Comment: And in C#: `byte[] byteArray = new byte[] {99, 0, 104, 0, 101, 0, 115, 0, 115, 0, 32, 0, 194, 0};` displays: `99 0 104 0 101 0 115 0 115 0 32 0 194 0`  `chess Â`

Comment: @Chris - and thanks for responding.  Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it's useful to someone looking at this - I've just tried encoding/decoding the string `"Â ¾"` in java - byte array outputs based on your output methods are `130 129 0 190 0 32 0 194` for UTF-16, `190 0 32 0 194 0` for UTF-16LE, and `0 190 0 32 0 194` for UTF-16BE.  All three successfully get decoded back to `"Â ¾"` using `new String(bytes, encoding)`

Comment: Is "chess"  relevant?

Comment: @WaiHaLee - no, just the special character. I guess it's there for context?

Comment: That one character is the only one that's >128 and as a result I'm very suspicious of `byteArray[i]<0?(-byteArray[i]+128):byteArray[i]));`

Comment: Changing the output function to just `byteArray[i]` and rerunning my Java sample: `"Â ¾"` becomes `-2 -1 0 -62 0 32 0 -66` for UTF-16, `-62 0 32 0 -66 0` for UTF-16LE, and `0 -62 0 32 0 -66` for UTF-16BE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not in the encoding, it is in the way you're printing the results, you are converting from byte to integer using `byteArray[i] < 0 ? (-byteArray[i] + 128) : byteArray[i]` which will give you incorrect results, use something else like `byteArray[i] & 0xFF` instead. compare both conversions using this poc:

```
    String encoding = "UTF-16LE";
    byte[] byteArray = "chess ¾".getBytes(encoding);
    for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
        // your conversion
        System.out.print(" " + (byteArray[i] < 0 ? (-byteArray[i] + 128) : byteArray[i]));
       // a more appropriate one
        System.out.print("(" + (byteArray[i] & 0xFF) + ") ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(new String(byteArray, encoding));
```

Comment: This also means that using UTF-8 was also working fine.

Comment: I would just like to add that the problem is not an overflow one.  It's just that the formula used was wrong, plain and simple. `byteArray[i] < 0 ? byteArray[i] + 256 : byteArray[i]` would have also worked fine, for instance.

Comment: @sstan you're right, lets call it an "underflow" caused by the `-` operation, as `byte b = -1; System.out.println(">> " + (-b))` would produce `>> 1` and not `>> -2`

Comment: @sstan on a second though, you're right, the problem is not underflow/overflow, the formula used is plain wrong

Comment: Thank you all - your help is greatly appreciated.   This is my favorite way of being wrong.

Answer (score 1):

My guess.

UTF-16LE means that characters take 2 or 4 bytes.

Check [this](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec) out and scroll down to 3/4. You will see both a 190 and a 194 (11000010 10111110) - these are the two bytes you need to encode the symbol, which is apparently called "VULGAR FRACTION THREE QUARTERS".

When you create a `byte[]`, the array can only store 1 byte, never two, so you will miss one. It looks like in C# you miss 194, and in Java you miss 190.

The reason is endianness. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793387/utf-16-encoding-in-java-versus-c-sharp) answer.

> In Java, getBytes("UTF-16") returns an a big-endian representation.
>
> C#'s System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes returns a little-endian representation.

However, in Java, `getBytes("UTF-16LE")` returns in little-endian according to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html), and that is what you are using.

I'm having doubts now.

I need to think more about what exactly you're doing in Java. Not sure yet how to resolve it.

Comment: Thanks for responding, @Pushkin.  Something like your concern led me away from using UTF-8 to UTF-16LE (as well as UTF-16BE).  The UTF-8 conversion to `byte[]` didn't loose any bytes - but their order was different between C# and Java (I've edited my original post to illustrate this).

Comment: See this posting (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9438470/4868078) for why I started using UTF-16LE.

Comment: UTF-16 is **always** in blocks of 16 bits - either one or two blocks per character. [From Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16): "*The encoding is variable-length, as code points are encoded with **one or two 16-bit code units**.*"